# Error using Tire persistence

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tire

I have an ActiveAdmin app with a simple model that I want to persist in Elastic Search with Tire:

```
class Person
  include Tire::Model::Persistence

  property :firstName
  property :lastName
end
```

But I get this error on the index action:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `quoted_table_name' for Person:Class)
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I skipped a few steps enabling Tire persistence. Thanks to [Chris Berkhout's post on this topic](http://chrisberkhout.com/blog/elasticsearch-as-a-primary-data-store/) my model now looks like this:

```
class Person
  include Tire::Model::Persistence
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  index_name ES_INDEX_NAME

  # Refresh ES so any changes are immediately visible
  refresh = lambda { Tire::Index.new(ES_INDEX_NAME).refresh }
  after_save &refresh
  after_destroy &refresh

  property :firstName
  property :lastName
  property :updated_at

  before_save { |n| n.updated_at = Time.now }

  def self.touch_es
    # Ensure a mapping in a fresh index, so that Note.all can sort on updated_at
    n = Person.new
    n.save
    n.destroy
  end

  def self.all
    # Override so that Note.all comes back sorted on updated_at, rather than _id
    search { sort { by :updated_at, 'desc' } }
  end

  def self.q(q)
    search { sort { by :updated_at, 'desc' }; query { string q } }
  end

end
```

And I needed to add a es.rake task in lib/tasks to set up the index:

```
namespace :es do
  desc "Delete the ElasticSearch index for the current environment"
  task :drop => :environment do
    Tire::Index.new(ES_INDEX_NAME).delete
  end
  desc "Create the ElasticSearch index for the current environment"
  task :create => :environment do
    Tire::Index.new(ES_INDEX_NAME).create
    Person.touch_es
  end
end
```

And an initializer es.rb in config/initializers to define the index name:

```
ES_INDEX_NAME = "#{Rails.application.class.parent_name.downcase}_#{Rails.env}"
```

Works a treat!

As for trying to get ActiveAdmin working with ES persistence, I see that AA is tied to ActiveRecord, though ActiveModel or an ORM-independent version is in the works.