# Indexing elasticsearch without active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

How can I use indexing on elastic search when there is no active record?
but model.rb specify just like this

```
class Article
  MIN_TERM_CHARS = 2
  MAX_NGRAM_CHARS = 20

  include SyncAttr
  include Tire::Model::Persistence


  index_name { Thread.current[:index_name] || "test" }
    document_type "document"

   # TODO: set index_options to doc for some fields for optimization

   # TODO: maybe use simple analyzer for 'id' fieldsart
  property :artikelnummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
  property :eannummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

  property :bezeichnung, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
    bezeichnung: {type: 'string'},
    ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'},
    suggest: {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'suggest_analyzer'}
  }
```

I want to index my data. How can I achieve this?
I am using [tire/karmi](http://rubygems.org/gems/tire)  for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `karmi/tire` gem has been [(re)tired](https://github.com/karmi/retire/wiki/Tire-Retire):

> It has been retired in September 2013, since a new library,
>   `https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby`, has been
>   released at that time.
>
> The new `elasticsearch` Ruby gem for Elasticsearch doesn't support all
>   the <strike>high-fructose</strike> high-level DSL of Tire, or the
>   automatic compatibility of search results with Rails' helpers such as
>   `url_for` or rich integration for your models.

Look at [`elasticsearch-ruby`](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby) for a more current ruby wrapper to elastic search API.

**Edit**

Just to clarify - `tire` is still usable, but its author recommends that you move to the new gem:

> If you're using Tire in a project, or contemplate to start using it,
>   these are the important points:
>
> 1. The **library will continue to work** as it did until now. In fact, it will certainly work better, **since bugs will be fixed and important
>      features will be added.**
> 2. All the **URLs will continue to work**, and be properly redirected by the browser, Git or Bundler. There is no need to change them unless
>      you want to.
> 3. The project has been renamed to increase the visibility of this migration, not just for fun.

Basic API usage of the new gem (from the [documentation](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/README.md)):

> ### Usage with the elasticsearch gem
>
> When you use the client from the `elasticsearch-ruby` package, the
>   library modules have been already included, so you just call the API
>   methods:
>
> ```
> require 'elasticsearch'
>
> client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
>
> client.index  index: 'myindex', type: 'mytype', id: 1, body: { title: 'Test' }
> # => {"_index"=>"myindex", ... "created"=>true}
>
> client.search index: 'myindex', body: { query: { match: { title: 'test' } } }
> # => {"took"=>2, ..., "hits"=>{"total":5, ...}}
> ```

Comment: are sure that tire/karmi can't be used-further?pl reply

Comment: See my edit - you can keep using them, but the author recommends using the new gem

Comment: but my question is how to index the data

Comment: Added an excerpt from the documentation

Comment: plz see my question's title

Comment: There is no active record in the example - simply use the `client.index` API.

Answer (score 1):

To index non model-backed objects, you can use the elasticsearch-ruby API (with the client.create syntax), as referenced by Uri. Elasticsearch-ruby is just a Ruby connector to Elasticsearch, so anything you can do with a regular curl request, you can do with the API, including setting up custom mappings, adding documents, and performing searches. I'm not sure if there's a way to index non model-backed objects using Tire, but I know that Tire can search any index, including indices not set-up by Tire (such as custom indices that you've set up using elasticsearch-ruby).

You can also use Tire to index model-backed objects while **bypassing ActiveRecord completely** (rather than using ActiveRecord callbacks) by including the `Tire::Persistence` module. To get it to work:

- Include the `Tire::Persistence` module in your model classes (as you've done).
- Disable ActiveRecord in `config/application.rb`, replacing the line `require 'rails/all'` with:

`require "rails"
[
  # 'active_record',
  'action_controller',
  'action_mailer',
  'active_resource',
  'rails/test_unit',
].each do |framework|
  begin
    require "#{framework}/railtie"
  rescue LoadError
  end
end`

- Delete `config/database.yml`
- remove 'gem sqlite3', or whatever database gem you've used, from the Gemfile.
- Run `bundle install`

See [this blog post](http://chrisberkhout.com/blog/elasticsearch-as-a-primary-data-store/) for more details, and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119919/error-using-tire-persistence) with a complete example of a working model that uses Elasticsearch to index objects rather than ActiveRecord.